# How is the '@' symbol correctly tokenized in a Java language parser?

Tags: java, parsing, token, grammar

I'm working on a Java source code parser, following the [lexical](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html) and [syntactic](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-18.html) specifications.

I'm stuck on annotations, though; the relevant rules are:

```
Annotation:
    @ QualifiedIdentifier [ ( [AnnotationElement] ) ]

AnnotationTypeDeclaration:
    @ interface Identifier AnnotationTypeBody
```

but I don't see the `@` symbol mentioned anywhere in the lexical spec.  What is the correct rule for tokenizing `@`, or where can I find such a rule?

I realize that I could easily add a token definition for this, and it might even work --- sometimes.  But I'd prefer to do it correctly according to the spec if possible.

Comment: Interesting! Those rules imply that `@ SomeAnnotation public @ interface Foo { }` is valid and indeed the compiler doesn't seem to complain about the added whitespace. So it looks like `@` is treated like a separate token (even 'though it's usually formatted with no whitespace between it and the next token).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In [9.6. Annotation Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.6) , it says:

> *Note that the at-sign (@) and the keyword interface are two distinct tokens. Technically it is possible to separate them with whitespace, but this is discouraged as a matter of style.*

Comment: Just what I was looking for, thanks.  Would the obvious way -- a new token that's just `@` -- be the correct way to implement this token?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, in the sense that '@' is not mentioned as either an operator or as punctuation in the "3. Lexical Structure" section of the JLS.

However, it is used as a symbol in the JLS 9.6, and also the "18. Collected Syntax" section, so it is obvious that your lexer should treat it as one.

This is just a minor editorial issue, and not something that should cause you any concern in implementing a Java parser.